# char to UTF16 conversion

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, type-conversion, utf-16, non-ascii-characters

I have an `unsigned char* array1` with values `>127 && <255`.
And I want to display it in `UITextView* MyTextView` and then read it back from `UITextView` to another `unsigned char* array2`. As result values in `array1` should equal to values in `array2`.

I understand that text property of `UITextView` is `NSString` object with UTF16 encoding inside.
And my codes greater then 127 are two-bite in UTF16 encoding. So if I want to display my array1 and receive read it back to array2 I need to proceed with steps:

1. convert my one-byte char to two-byte with replacement of each char with mapping UTF18(as result my array1 will become twice bigger).
2. convert my array1 to NSString using UTF16 encoding;
3. convert my NSString back to array2 with UTF16encoding.
4. convert each two-byte sequence to one byte char of array2.

How I can convert my non-ASCII chars >127 to UTF16? Use mapping?

Code:

```
UITextView* MyTextView;//assume this exists

unsigned char array1[] = {130,150,250};

unsigned char *array2 = malloc(4);

MyTextView.text = [NSString stringWithCString:array1 encoding: NSUTF16StringEncoding];
[MyTextView.text getCString:array2 length:MyTextView.text encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

As result values of `array1` and `array2` differs.

Please help to understand and convert my chars >127 to UTF16.

Comment: What characters do 130, 150, 250 represent? In other words, which encoding or character set is used for the non-ASCII bytes? Without that information, it is impossible to answer your question properly.

Comment: For example, 130 is hex 0x82, but the Unicode U+0082 is "BREAK PERMITTED HERE", which is a control character. - So just displaying arbitrary bytes does not make sense without any encoding information.

Comment: Martin R, I just use array1 to hold values, it doesnt matter forme what charactters this values represent. Values are one-byte and I want to store them on the screen in the way that later i can read them back and receive 130 150 250in one byte each. For example i can store 130 as 127 in first byte and the remainder 3 in second byte.then display it in uitextview using utf16encod. After that read back to array2 using utf16encod (first byte 127 and second3) and just sum them and store in one-byte char.with value 130.?what do you think about ths? My algorith works with one byte values so need them